# How to upload files & Get the public url Google Drive Api?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-drive-api

I create a simple website for Uploading files on Google Drive using Google Drive Api.

This is My Code :

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
                
            },
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=webViewLink",
            data:{
                uploadType:"media"
            },
            xhr: function () {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', that.progressHandling, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            async: true,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            timeout: 60000
        });
    };
   
    
    Upload.prototype.progressHandling = function (event) {
        var percent = 0;
        var position = event.loaded || event.position;
        var total = event.total;
        var progress_bar_id = "#progress-wrp";
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
        }
        // update progressbars classes so it fits your code
        $(progress_bar_id + " .progress-bar").css("width", +percent + "%");
        $(progress_bar_id + " .status").text(percent + "%");
    };

    $("#upload").on("click", function (e) {
        var file = $("#files")[0].files[0];
        var upload = new Upload(file);
    
        // maby check size or type here with upload.getSize() and upload.getType()
    
        // execute upload
        upload.doUpload();
    });



    
});
```

Everything is Oky, But I just want to get the public URL of The files  I just want to show the public url after file uploaded. Help Me Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after upload the file and getting the fileId:

```
async function generatePublicUrl(fileId) {
  try {
    await drive.permissions.create({
      fileId: fileId,
      requestBody: {
        role: "reader",
        type: "anyone",
      },
    });
    const result = await drive.files.get({
      fileId: fileId,
      fields: "webViewLink, webContentLink",
    });
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

and after doing that you just put your fileId in the format:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/"yourfileId"/preview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/%22yourfileId%22/preview)

Comment: Can you please help me to implement this two codes? This is my Full code : [ https://pastebin.com/raw/eSCMaxdJ ] Please help me to implement your code.

Comment: after uploading the file to google drive you get an uploaded file. and after getting the id and then create permission: check this link I hope you find https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

Comment: also check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644989/how-to-change-file-permission-with-api-google-drive

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive api does not have a method for creating the sharable link.

You will need to manually go to the Google drive website and create your sharable link there and store it in your system.